# как добавить инлайн кнопку,после каждой позиции в sql?

Tags: python, telegram-bot, sqlite, telegram, aiogram

как добавить инлайн кнопку,после каждой позиции в sql?Сейчас выводится только одна кнопка после всех позиций

```
if message.text == 'fdgdg':
    await bot.send_message(message.from_user.id, 'Менioю',reply_markup=turei_kb)
    await sqlite_db.sql_read(message)
```

и вот отрывок кода из другого файла

```
    async def sql_read(message):
        global base, cur
        base = sqlite3.connect('pizza_cool.db')
        cur = base.cursor()
        for ret in cur.execute('SELECT * FROM menu').fetchall():
            await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена {ret[-1]}')
```

Answer (score 0):

Добавить `reply_markup=turei_kb` вот в эту строку:

```
await bot.send_photo(message.from_user.id, ret[0], f'{ret[1]}\nОписание: {ret[2]}\nЦена {ret[-1]}')
```

и убрать из первого кода.

Comment: добро пожаловать на Stack Overflow на русском! похоже, это не ответ, а дополнение к вопросу. если так и есть, то дополните, пожалуйста, текст вопроса, нажав ссылку «править» ниже текста вопроса, а данный «ответ», пожалуйста, удалите